# RHEL5: htop shows empty command-column

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5, htop

When issue the command htop on my RHEL5 box I get a normal view, however when I scroll down I have several "blank" command ranges as can be seen here:

[image]

Can someone explain me how this happens/occurs?

**Update:**

my .htoprc file:

```
# Beware! This file is rewritten every time htop exits.
# The parser is also very primitive, and not human-friendly.
# (I know, it's in the todo list).
fields=0 48 17 18 38 39 40 2 46 47 49 1
sort_key=46
sort_direction=1
hide_threads=0
hide_kernel_threads=1
hide_userland_threads=0
shadow_other_users=0
show_thread_names=0
highlight_base_name=0
highlight_megabytes=1
highlight_threads=0
tree_view=0
header_margin=1
detailed_cpu_time=0
color_scheme=0
delay=15
left_meters=AllCPUs Memory Swap
left_meter_modes=1 1 1
right_meters=Tasks LoadAverage Uptime
right_meter_modes=2 2 2
```

Comment: I meet this problem. ps -e show this PIDs as kernel threads. For example 

2 migration/0
3 ksoftirqd/0
4 watchdog/0
...

Answer (score 1):

Should be in .config/htop/htoprc or something similar.

I'd say you have this line in your config file

```
shadow_other_users=1
```

You should put it at 0. Otherwise if you start htop with your user it will shadow other users' processes.
Can you please post your htoprc file if this doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, it already was set to 0. I've updated the post with the htoprc file which was located in /root/.htoprc

Comment: I see, under which user do you run htop ?
Can you see other processes other than init ?
Did it work good already or is the problem there since the beginning ?

Comment: I run htop as the root user. This didn't happen in the begin. I can still see other processes with normal output. Because this are low pids I think they are some kernel threads that have gone wrong. I also aknowledge that an uptime of 1024 days may have something to do with it.

Comment: Ah, that's true, that could happen. The only parameter I know I gave you, so good luck now.

Answer (score 1):

I found that for Red Hat EL 5 and htop 1.0.3 I had to make the following code change to get the command to show up for root processes.  I did not need to make this changes to Red Hat 6 EL.

```
--- Process.c   2014-01-01 12:00:00.000000000 -0400
+++ Process.c.patched   2014-01-01 12:00:00.000000000 -0400
@@ -52,7 +52,7 @@
 #define PROCESS_FLAG_CGROUP 16

 #ifndef Process_isKernelThread
-#define Process_isKernelThread(_process) (_process->pgrp == 0)
+#define Process_isKernelThread(_process) (_process->pgrp == 1)
 #endif

 #ifndef Process_isUserlandThread
```